# How to export arrangeGrob output via win.metafile()

Tags: r, rstudio

I need to save plots from R as EMF format (windows metafile format) because this makes the chart look good on screen and paper in Microsoft Word. No other option (PNG, postscript etc) works well on both. The `PNG` device produces poor res plots. Tinkering with `res` parameters blows up the graph elements and I can't find anything that clearly explains how to mitigate this. Using `postscript` print output is pretty good. However, Word's EPS filters are busted so that I can't see the EPS file on screen. I need something that works well on screen and on paper. `win.metafile` is only thing that does both.

Here's the twist. I am using `gridExtra` to customise the layout of my plots. From what I gather, this means that I am writing multiple plots onto one device (which I then want to export to EMF). But I know that `win.metafile` only allows one plot per file. From `?win.metafile`:

> For win.metafile only one plot is allowed per file

So the following shouldn't work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
# g_legend pinched from Hadley:
# https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs
g_legend <- function(a.gplot)
{
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
}
win.metafile(file='test.emf', width=6, height=4)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, colour=factor(gear)))
pl <- p + geom_point()
legend <- g_legend(pl)
lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
pp <- arrangeGrob(pl + theme(legend.position="none"), legend)
pp
dev.off()
```

In fact I get the following error message:

> Error in grid.newpage() : metafile 'test.emf' could not be created

Ok. So here's my question: **how can I trick `win.metafile` to see only one plot from the arrangeGrob output**? Can I stuff its output into *something* and get *one* plot out? It must be possible because if I use RStudio's export function, I get an excellent looking chart on screen and paper. But I want to codify this so I don't have to manually export the files.

I've scoured the web and haven't been able to find anything that addresses this. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `ggsave('test.wmf',pp)`? I could only test with PDF since I'm not using a Windows system at the moment.

Comment: I get the following error, when using just ggsave('test.emf'):
> Error in grid.newpage() : metafile 'test.emf' could not be created

Comment: This makes sense because ggsave is a wrapper for win.metafile, png and other such functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this just now using the `devEMF` package, and though it throws a warning it looks like the picture that you've created here.

You just need to `install.packages('devEMF')` and then:

```
require(devEMF)
emf('imPic.emf')
print(pp)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Have problems with rotated text, but otherwise works as I would like it to. Why this isn't part of `base` is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, did notice that the core dev team helped out with code for this package.